# Dropdown menu disappears when the mouse isn't over a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I tried to make a dropdown menu using Jquery but when you try to select the second link the menu disappears. Also, how would I make it so only one dropdown menu can appear at once?

How would I need to change this to fix it?

```
$('#nav a').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
$('#nav ul ul').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);
function openSubMenu(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown(300);
};
function closeSubMenu(){
    $(this).closest('ul').slideUp(300);
};
```

Example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/g36tywLc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mouseleave` instead:

```
$('#nav ul ul').bind('mouseleave', closeSubMenu);
```

Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g36tywLc/1/).

From [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseleave_mouseout):

> The mouseout event triggers when the mouse pointer leaves any child
>   elements as well the selected element. 
>   The mouseleave event is only triggered when the mouse pointer leaves the selected element.

Comment: Thanks! That was simpler than I thought it would be. Also, is it possible to stop more than one dropdown menu from appearing at once? (This happens when you go directly to the next dropdown menu rather than going into the one you just opened.

Comment: @AmperPil, add a function to close all open submenus at the top of `openSubMenu`.

Comment: @kaz It seems that after that last update, it now reverts to how it started to react.

Comment: So it did.  Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g36tywLc/3/) - note I had to add some classes to the menu titles.